# Is it possible to specify a database and schema within a linqtosql query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using linqtosql to query a database directly (not as am ORM).

I have the following code which works:

```
var events = 
    from e in Events
    select e.EventID;
```

What I would like to do is expand it to join to a second table within a different database / schema on the same SQL instance. For example:

```
var events = 
    from e in Events
    join p in database2.dbo.People on p.PersonID equals e.PersonID 
    select e.EventID;
```

How would I go about specifying the database / schema within the linq query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible out of the box. But if you only want a select, you can create a view to the second database and add that to your DBML.